# Getting Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to AngularJs and some things are still unknown to me. Lots of them actually.

I have this error in my browser:

```
Unknown provider: URLsProvider <- URLs <- AuthenticationInterceptor <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state
```

When I go to Angularjs help page [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=URLsProvider%20%3C-%20URLs%20%3C-%20AuthenticationInterceptor%20%3C-%20$http%20%3C-%20$templateFactory%20%3C-%20$view%20%3C-%20$state) I get this explanation that I am missing or doing wrongly injection in my code.

I got this code from the internet, and all it should do is to be an interceptor that will add jwt token to request header each time I make some call.

Here is the code:

```
export default function(AuthenticationService, URLs) {
    let service = this;

    service.request = function(config) {
        let token = AuthenticationService.getToken();
        if(config.url.indexOf(URLs.API) === 0 && token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token;
        }

        return config;
    };
}
```

This is the service:

```
class AuthenticationService {
    constructor($window) {
        this.$window = $window;
        this.tokenKey = "examinoJwtToken";
    }

    saveToken(token) {
        this.$window.localStorage[this.tokenKey] = token;
    }

    getToken() {
        return this.$window.localStorage[this.tokenKey];
    }

    login(token) {
        this.saveToken(token);
    }

    logout() {
        this.$window.localStorage.removeItem(this.tokenKey);
    }

    parseJwt(token) {
        var base64Url = token.split(".")[1];
        var base64 = base64Url.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/");
        return JSON.parse(this.$window.atob(base64));
    }

    isAuthenticated() {
        var token = this.getToken();
        if(token) {
            var params = this.parseJwt(token);
            return Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) <= params.exp;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And in app.js I have added this:

```
import AuthenticationService from "./shared/services/AuthenticationService";
import AuthenticationInterceptor from "./shared/interceptors/AuthenticationInterceptor";
```

export default AuthenticationService;
AuthenticationService is a service where all functionalities are defined. Like: getToken, saveToken, login, etc.

Do I need to inject this service? Or do you maybe see some other problem? What is the solution to this? I know it may be trivial thing, but I have never touch AngularJs in my life before, so I need to ask for help and extra explanation.

Comment: what is `URLs`?

Comment: @PankajParkar Hmmm that is a good question. This is the problem when you copy someones code. Let me try to remove that somehow for this piece. :)